# Unsafely define struct to share mutable references between threads

Tags: multithreading, rust, unsafe

I need to **unsafely** define a Rust struct that I can share between 2 threads and mutate the content of the struct from both threads.

I do not want to use `Mutex` nor `RwLock` because I want to implement the thread safety myself. For performance concerns, I do not want to check the mutex when time I want to access the content and I know it is not in the critical section.

If I only use `Arc` to share the struct between threads, I get *`cannot borrow data in an Arc as mutable`* and *`help: trait DerefMut is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for std::sync::Arc<Foo>`*.

The **safe way** to do this:

```
struct Foo {
    bar: usize,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn set_bar(&mut self, a: usize) {
        self.bar = a;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { bar: 32 };
    foo.bar = 33;

    let foo_arc = std::sync::Arc::new(std::sync::Mutex::new(foo));
    let foo_arc_2 = std::sync::Arc::clone(&foo_arc);

    let handle = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        foo_arc_2.lock().unwrap().set_bar(32);
    });
    foo_arc.lock().unwrap().set_bar(31);
    handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

What I **unsafely** want to achieve:

```
struct Foo {
    bar: usize,

    // My own lock
    // lock: std::sync::Mutex<usize>,
}

unsafe impl Sync for Foo {}

impl Foo {
    pub fn set_bar(&mut self, a: usize) {
        self.bar = a;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { bar: 32 };
    foo.bar = 33;

    let foo_arc = std::sync::Arc::new(foo);
    let foo_arc_2 = std::sync::Arc::clone(&foo_arc);

    let handle = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        foo_arc_2.set_bar(32);
    });
    foo_arc.set_bar(31);
    handle.join().unwrap();
}
```

I might not have to use `Arc` and use something more low level unknown to me at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this to later use it in production, **don't** do it! Many people smarter than you and me already done this correctly. Use what they wrote instead. If you want to do this as an exercise, or for learning purposes, then go ahead and **do** it.

If you want to provide a type with *interior mutability* then you must use [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html). This type is at a core of every interior mutability in rust and using it is **the only way to get a `&mut T` from `&T`**. You should read really carefully it's documentation, the documentation of the `cell` module and The Nomicon (preferably all of it, but at least [concurrency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/concurrency.html) chapter).

If you prefer watching videos, Jon Gjengset has, among many others, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8O0Nt9qY_vo) **amazing** video on cell types. And [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMGWeSjctlY) video on atomic memory and implementing (bad) mutex.

Comment: Thank you very much, great answer! If I wanted to use this for more than an exercise, there is no way to avoid using the `Mutex`, right @Aleksander Krauze ?

Comment: @javier Well, it depends. `std::sync::Mutex` is a good place to start, but it is not the best solution in high contingency scenarios.  There is no universal answer, because each problem requires different approach and each person might be willing to take different trade-offs. You can look at [lib.rs](https://lib.rs/concurrency) and see if you see there something that looks nice for you.

Comment: Nitpick: "get a `&mut T` from `&T`" is UB even with `UnsafeCell`. What it allows is going from `&Wrapper<T>` to `&mut T` (where `Wrapper` can be `Cell`, `RefCell`, `Mutex`, etc., including `UnsafeCell` itself).